# Azure Search Suggester - Why return duplicate value?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

As a user is typing in a filter field, I want to show an autocomplete containing suggestions.

I'm trying to use Azure Search Suggester for that, but it returns duplicate values ?

ex:

```
POST /indexes/assets/docs/suggest?api-version=2016-09-01 HTTP/1.1
Host: xxx.search.windows.net
api-key: xxx
Content-Type: application/json

{
    search: 'bank',
    suggesterName: 'sg',
    top:5,
    searchFields: "accountName",
    select: 'accountName'
}
```

What is being returned:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://xxx.search.windows.net/indexes('assets')/$metadata#docs(accountName)",
  "value": [
    {
      "@search.text": "CAIXA BANK",
      "accountName": "CAIXA BANK"
    },
    {
      "@search.text": "CAIXA BANK",
      "accountName": "CAIXA BANK"
    },
    {
      "@search.text": "BANK OF AMERICA",
      "accountName": "BANK OF AMERICA"
    },
    {
      "@search.text": "BANK OF AMERICA",
      "accountName": "BANK OF AMERICA"
    },
    {
      "@search.text": "BANK OF AMERICA",
      "accountName": "BANK OF AMERICA"
    }
  ]
}
```

I was expecting the result to contains 5 different accountName, not repeated values for each documents having the same accountName...

I'm a missing something here ?

**EDIT**

It seems to be the expected behavior, suggestion return distinct documents ... It makes no sense to me, if I would like to retrieve documents I would do a query, not a suggestion.

What is the use cases of suggestions then if we can't use them to populate autocomplete fields ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Distinct values in Azure Search Suggestions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32207000/distinct-values-in-azure-search-suggestions)

Comment: You can use the Autocomplete API that does the grouping by default.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/autocomplete However, if you need any other field together with the suggested term, this API won't fit your needs. So, either do a Suggest call and group items yourself or use the Autocomplete API.

Answer (score 3):

As the link in the comment pointed out, Suggest API in Azure Search suggests documents not query terms. Suggest API returns *document IDs* associated with the matched field. Common use cases would be to find newspaper articles whose titles match or products whose names match the searched terms/phrases.

Some customers are using the Suggest API for autocompleting search fields. In such cases, we suggest deduping the returned field on the client side or use a secondary index. The feature however isn't designed for that. We are in fact working on a new feature that suggests *search terms* from the corpus for autocompleting purposes. I will update the thread when the feature is available.

Nate

Comment: If Suggest API returns documents, I still don't get how is it different than the Search API then ? Deduping in the caller make the Top parameter useless... ex: using Top:20 and all returned documents have the same value...

Comment: Glad it is being worked on. The use case is simple: think Google suggestions... terms are being returned, not specific pages.

Comment: They are actually not too different. Suggest API is a special version of Search specifically tailored for commonly used type-ahead like scenarios where searched terms are only partially complete and response time is important and etc. You can actually pretty much mimic Suggest API with Search with custom analyzers (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/custom-analyzers-in-azure-search) except it's already done for you in Suggest API.