# Is it possible to get a list of unique field values from an azure search index?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I have an azure search index which has a field DocumentId. On performing the search with a keyword, I need to get a list of unique DocumentId entries.
Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 0):

For the query it will be something like this:

```
search=keyword&searchFields=DocumentId
```

but there's no distinct option in Azure Search, since it's an expensive task. You'll need to perform it in your backend:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56699157/1384539